# Holomorph of Cyclic $p$-groups

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, cyclic-groups, p-groups, holomorph

Assume that $G$ is a cyclic $p$-group (or up to isomorphism more explicitly $\mathbb{Z}_{p^r}$). Do you know if there does exist any explicit way to describe the holomorph of the above group? Moreover, do you know if we can say something about the representations of these groups? (modular, non-modular)

Comment: To compute the holomorph of a cyclic group $G$ generated by an element $g$ you need to find the normalizer of the image $L$ of $G$ in the symmetric group $S(G)$ of the permutations given by multiplying on tthe left by elements of $G$. Now $L$ is clearly generated as a group by th permuation given by multiplication by $g$, and that permutation is has a very simple cycle decomposition: it is just one cycle of length $|G|$. Can you compute the normalizer?

Comment: Thank you for your response,i guess the answer is yes for your question, however i didn't try yet. But i don't understand something. This normalizer is isomorphic with the holomorph?

Comment: The holomorph of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^r}$ is the Galois group of $X^{p^r}-p$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. This also gives a representation into $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thank you Clement! Do you know, where can find an analytic proof for the above? Or if it is easy, can you give a hint?

Answer (score 0):

My representation theory is almost nada.

But the holomorph is, ims, the canonical semi-direct product  $G\rtimes\rm_\varphi  {Aut}G $, with the action  being left multiplication.

So we get  $\mathbb Z_{p^r}\rtimes_\varphi\mathbb Z_{p^r-p^{r-1}} $, unless  $p=2$.